# Gerando modelo a partir do banco de dados - tabela com um atributo e Herança

Tags: entity-framework-6

No projeto que estou trabalhando estou com as seguintes duvidas:

Primeiramente, fiz umas tabelas de heranças no banco de dados em que cada uma possuem só uma coluna o id(que é pk e fk da tabela ao qual fazem herança), e ao gerar o modelo(edmx) a partir do banco de dados as tabelas que possuem só uma coluna não são criadas, existe alguma configuração onde posso configurar isso? 
Já procurei e não encontrei nada relacionado.

Em segundo gostaria de saber se quando o modelo é gerado também há alguma configuração onde possa escolher as tabelas que serão herança para serem geradas com a configuração correta, pois senão toda vez tenho que fazer a herança na mão. O que torna o processo custoso.

OBS: Uso o EF6.

Exemplo do modelo parecido ao qual estou usando:

Homologacao(Entidade):
id,
situacao,
categoria,
telefone,
enderecos

Homologacao_curso(Entidade com Herança):
id (é primary key e foreing key referenciando a entidade homologacao)
id_curso(fk da entidade curso)

homologacao_capacitadora(Entidade com Herança):
id (é primary key e foreing key referenciando a entidade homologacao)

1º Problema:
Ao gerar o edmx as as únicas entidades geradas são homologacao e homologacao_curso. Como a entidade homologacao_capacitadora não precisa de outro dado a não ser o id ela não é gerada.

Comment: Coloque o modelo do seu banco de dados!

Comment: Espero que tenha ficado mais claro agora.

Comment: Se você estiver criando um banco de dados do zero, seria melhor você usar o Code First do EF, é muito fácil. Posso postar uma resposta com exemplo de como ficaria uma modelagem se quiser.

Comment: Guilherme quais foram as classes criadas?

Comment: @RodrigoK.B infelizmente no projeto que estou foi deifinido a usar o edmx para geração das entidades no .Net. Também preferia usar o EF6 Code FIrst, mas infelizmente estou preso a esse :(.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic no caso ele cria somente a entidade Pessoa, caso as entidades pessoa_fisica e pessoa_juridica conterem somente o atributo id. Mas caso eu adicione mais algum atributo a elas, o edmx gera elas sem problema.

Comment: Então não entendi o problema!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic então como mostrei esse modelo é um exemplo, porém tenho entidades que serão heranças e não possuem nenhum atributo além do ID, e quando gero o edmx ele não reconhece essas entidades.

Comment: Então o seu modelo Guilherme tem problemas, porque, criar um tabela com um campo que faz referencia a uma outra tabela não tem a necessidade de existir. Sempre nesse caso deve existir outros campos!

Comment: Também havia pensado nisso, porém como nesse caso a herança foi a melhor solução. Porém algumas entidades que herdam dessa entidade possuem somente o campo id, assim evito de encher a entidade pai com foreign keys. Vou atualizar o modelo para o que uso para deixar as coisas mais claras.

Comment: Como é isso aqui  [homologacao_capacitadora(Entidade com Herança): id (é primary key e foreing key referenciando a entidade homologacao)]  VOCÊ TEM UMA TABELA COM O CAMPO **ID** QUE É **PK E FK** ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, esse campo é usado para realizar a herança da entidade quando o diagrama do edmx é gerado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você pode acrescentar a entidade homologacao_capacitadora no **designer do edmx** e mapear para a tabela desejada e assinale a entidade como sendo uma **sub-classe**